# How do I display a field name containing the substring OMIT in ApEx?

Tags: oracle-apex

One of the fields in my database table is named DATEOFDISCHARGEFROMITU.  In any report output, this displays as DATEOFDISCHARGEFRU. I've figured out that the missing characters form the word 'OMIT', which makes me think it's related to [this old problem in a previous version of ApEx](https://community.oracle.com/thread/636239?start=0&tstart=0) (I'm using version 4.1.)

Is there a way to display the whole field name in the report header when the field name contains the string 'OMIT'?

Note: Using html character codes will allow the field name to *display* properly, but then when the report is exported to CSV the character codes are of course shown instead of the full field name. I need a solution that works for exports as well as displaying onscreen.

Comment: Hi, are you using a query to bring the data back to the report?, if so can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms (tested):** Oracle Application Express (APEX), Version 4.0.2

> Note:  I am not sure how the linked OTN post is relevant to your problem aside from the coincidence that their file export contains the word "OMIT" and your column title contains the word "OMIT".

*It's safe to say that "OMIT" isn't an APEX or ORACLE reserved word that is sabotaging your output. However, if you were talking about a scrap of SQL that attempted to create a table named "SELECT" or "WHERE"*

```
    i.e., SELECT * FROM "SELECT" WHERE...
```

*you'll be blocked by the RDBMS from proceeding.* :)

I tried an export with a query that contained a column header labeled "OMIT" (see the far right in the example.)  The .csv file interpreted by Microsoft Excel looked like this:

[image: CSV File Export with a special "Keyword" Header]

I wrote up a separate Q&A post about [creating dynamic APEX report headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156968/how-do-i-customize-column-headers-with-html-in-a-report-region-of-an-oracle-apex/24156969#24156969) to answer your follow-on question about a suitable solution for providing a clean, htmlcode-free output when a report is eventually exported to a text, comma separated (or other delimited) output.

In summary, the linked post suggests to set up a dynamic PL/SQL Function within a page item.  The page item can be referenced directly in the report column header definition.  This is a screenshot demonstrating a possible solution:

[image: Dynamic APEX Report Attributes]

The link to the general explanation has more details on the APEX design tasks that gets to this final product.

Onward.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using this [solution for exporting to csv without an enclosing quote character](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1082882?tstart=0) - as that was another challenge I was faced with for the particular application I was developing. By manually creating the export file I was also able to define the column headings exactly, and the "OMIT" issue did not occur.

Technically that's not a solution for displaying a report with the required headings that can also be exported (Richard's response does that) but it does what I need it to and solves the immediate problem of the DATEOFDISCHARGEFROMITU column heading.

Comment: I like the solution adapted from the OTN problem to your own situation.  If it serves its purpose, no additional comment is necessary as it has nicely been figured out.  It may be useful to the APEX community on SO to see your example of a "manually" reworked csv export format.  Edit it to your existing answer here for us to see!  Thanks for posting.